# generated declaration file (d.ts) with bad imports

Tags: typescript

This library `tsconfig.json` has `"declaration": true` and so during the build a lot of `d.ts` declaration files are generated.

The library provides some React components that import their styles like so:
`import './Widget.scss'`

These import statements are output in the `d.ts` declaration files. That makes the declaration files invalid because there are no sass files copied into the build output folder having the `d.ts` files.

The webpack-directed build ends up generating a single `index.css`. It could be configured to generate a lot of css files and put them into the folders with the `d.ts` files. But still the imports would be invalid as they would look for the `scss` file, and, it doesn't seem to make much sense to copy the `scss` files to try to make the `d.ts` files valid.

It seems like if these `import 'Widget.scss'` lines were filtered out of the `d.ts` files or not emitted in the first place, that would be the simplest way to make the `d.ts` files valid.

There's a lot of docs on how to import scss modules into typescript.  Some docs show how to use scss with typescript and it is done the same in this project, but in this project also the `d.ts` files are generated, a bit less common scenario.